# Jquery.append() in certain position of class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code:

```
var $collapsibleProducts = $('.collapsible-body');
if ($collapsibleProducts.length != 0) {
  $.each($('.collapsible-body'), function (i) { 
    if ($('.collapsible-body')[i].children.length === 0) {
      $('.collapsible-body')[i].append("<span class='something'>something</span>")
    }
  });
}
```

But I only getting inside my `div.collapsible-body` this string `"<span class='something'>something</span>"` instead of html `<span>` tag with 'something' string.

Like [this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz4Ov.png)

Is there something I doing wrong? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: `$('.collapsible-body')[i]` <-- returns DOM, it does not have an append method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check for the length (jQuery's easy like that), and you're using the wrong kind of each. You're using [the general iterator](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) whereas jQuery has [a special iterator for jQuery objects](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
var $collapsibleProducts = $('.collapsible-body');

$collapsibleProducts.each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).children().length === 0) {
    $(el).append("<span class='something'>something</span>");
  }
});
```